# Magento Cybersrouce cavvAlgorithm for processor ATOS

Tags: magento, payment-gateway

Not a question but a information.

If you are having issues with processor ATOS failing because of the lack of the cavvAlgorithm not being send then check that the module WSDL is updated to the latest version, current version i can find is 1.111 not 1.26 
Url is in 2 files:

app\code\core\Mage\Cybersource\Model\Soap.php

If using CybersourceAuth extension:

CybersourceAuth\Model\Api.php

change the constants from

```
const WSDL_URL_TEST = 'https://ics2wstest.ic3.com/commerce/1.x/transactionProcessor/CyberSourceTransaction_1.26.wsdl';
const WSDL_URL_LIVE = 'https://ics2ws.ic3.com/commerce/1.x/transactionProcessor/CyberSourceTransaction_1.26.wsdl';
```

to

```
const WSDL_URL_TEST = 'https://ics2wstest.ic3.com/commerce/1.x/transactionProcessor/CyberSourceTransaction_1.111.wsdl';
const WSDL_URL_LIVE = 'https://ics2ws.ic3.com/commerce/1.x/transactionProcessor/CyberSourceTransaction_1.111.wsdl';
```

Comment: Questions and subsequent self-answer are allowed on Stackoverflow - and by the looks of it what you've written may well be found useful by members of the community at some point, so thanks for adding it. However as it stands you've got an answer without a question.  You should reframe this so that you pose a problem first 'Why is  CyberSource authentication failing via default SOAP API' and then provide your solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are having issues with processor ATOS failing because of the lack of the cavvAlgorithm not being send then check that the module WSDL is updated to the latest version, current version i can find is 1.111 not 1.26 
Url is in 2 files:

app\code\core\Mage\Cybersource\Model\Soap.php

If using CybersourceAuth extension:

CybersourceAuth\Model\Api.php

change the constants from

```
const WSDL_URL_TEST = 'https://ics2wstest.ic3.com/commerce/1.x/transactionProcessor/CyberSourceTransaction_1.26.wsdl';
const WSDL_URL_LIVE = 'https://ics2ws.ic3.com/commerce/1.x/transactionProcessor/CyberSourceTransaction_1.26.wsdl';
```

to

```
const WSDL_URL_TEST = 'https://ics2wstest.ic3.com/commerce/1.x/transactionProcessor/CyberSourceTransaction_1.111.wsdl';
const WSDL_URL_LIVE = 'https://ics2ws.ic3.com/commerce/1.x/transactionProcessor/CyberSourceTransaction_1.111.wsdl';
```